# How to get tax rate for products with BigCommerce API?

Tags: php, bigcommerce

I'm working with Bigcommerce API using PHP. I've created a trial store and I've setup the 'Tax Rates & Zones' in my store settings. Now I want to know what's the tax rate for products. Bigcommerce API has https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/tax endpoints, but it only return tax class objects which only have an ID and Name.

Also in order resources there is Order Tax object which has the tax rate. But there is no way I can access it outside orders.

How do I access the store tax rates outside order resources?

Thanks.

Comment: In which technology you are working? edit and mention

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, in PHP

Comment: I need an answer too, there is no way to find out which product in salesOrder has applied tax using https://www.bigcommerceClient.com/api/v2/orders/127/taxes

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to currently get Zone or Rate information about taxes, but we do now offer avatax as a tool. Future releases will include tax zone and rates.

More info on the upcoming api roadmap is here: https://trello.com/b/1Od4oCsl/bigcommerce-api-roadmap